# How to extract alphanumeric word from string in dart?

Tags: regex, dart

I have a string like as follows.

```dart
var string = "My id is 6aT7u. I used to play basketball and cricket.";
```

I have to extract the ID, i.e an alphanumeric word, using a regex. I have to extract `6aT7u` in this case.

I tried `[a-zA-Z0-9]` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```dart
\b(?:\d+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]+\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8aprDG/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:\d+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]+\d)` - a non-capturing group matching either

  - `\d+[A-Za-z]` - one or more digits and then an ASCII letter
  - `|` - or
  - `[A-Za-z]+\d` - one or more ASCII letters and then a digit
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - zero or more ASCII digits or letters
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Gettting the first match in Dart can be done with a code like

```dart
var string = "My id is 6aT7u. I used to play basketball and cricket.";
  var rx = RegExp(r'\b(?:\d+[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]+\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]*\b');
  var match = rx.firstMatch(string);
  if (match != null) {
    print(match.group(0));
  }
// => 6aT7u
```